# Prevent query string manipulation by adding a hash?

Tags: asp.net, security, hash, query-string

To protect a web application from query string manipulation, I was considering adding a query string parameter to every url which stores a SHA1 hash of all the other query string parameters & values, then validating against the hash on every request.

Does this method provide strong protection against user manipulation of query string values? Are there any other downsides/side-effects to doing this?

I am not particularly concerned about the 'ugly' urls for this private web application. Url's will still be 'bookmarkable' as the hash will always be the same for the same query string arguments.

This is an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Why not just use real security/authentication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure this provides any sort of security. If a man-in-the-middle attacker wants to change the parameters, all they must do is change the query string and recompute the SHA-1 hash and send that request along to the server.

For example, the URL sent by the browser might be:

[http://www.example.com/addUser.html?parameterA=foo&hash=SHA1("parameterA=foo")](http://www.example.com/addUser.html?parameterA=foo&hash=SHA1(%22parameterA=foo%22))

If an attacker intercepts this, they can edit it in this way:

[http://www.example.com/adduser.html?parameterA=bar&hash=SHA1("parameterA=bar")](http://www.example.com/adduser.html?parameterA=bar&hash=SHA1(%22parameterA=bar%22))

Really, this boils down to the fact you can trust the hash only as much as the parameters themselves.

One way you could fix this would be if the user has a password that only they and the server knows, then it would be impossible for the attacker to recompute the hash if they change the parameters. For example:

[http://www.example.com/addUser.html?parameterA=foo&hash=SHA1("parameterA=foo"+"theuserpassword")](http://www.example.com/addUser.html?parameterA=foo&hash=SHA1(%22parameterA=foo%22+%22theuserpassword%22))

But don't put the password as one of the parameters in the URL :)

It is important to note that this isn't the state of the art for verifying the integrity of messages passed between two parties. What is used today is a form of the Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) algorithm, which is pretty well described in [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), and definitively in [RFC2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) and [FIPS Pub 198-1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips198-1/FIPS-198-1_final.pdf).

Comment: You can simply have a Salt for the Hash to prevent manipulation/man-in-the-middle etc.

Comment: If you mean salts that are like /etc/passwd salts, then these don't provide any safety against mitm attacks. Salts are in general public knowledge and only serve to make it more difficult to reverse a hash using brute force attacks. The 'salt' (really the key in a keyed hash) must be secret in order to prevent the attacker from being able to change and recompute the digest. This is basically an authentication scheme, which generally requires some sort of shared secret knowledge before hand.

Comment: I think as long as the salt is very random and kept secret, this will be an acceptable solution.

Comment: For a *great* description of salts and how they're used in security, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190

Comment: @novalis, you are right that this isn't state-of-the-art. My intention was to simply describe the concept of HMAC without confusing the discussion with padding. To clarify, I have added a paragraph noting this and referencing the proper RFC and NIST publications.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to prevent query string manipulation with no hash:

In the global.asax file

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I take the url referer host. (manipulating the query string this value is null or your local address)
    string strRefererHost = Request.UrlReferrer == null ? string.Empty : Request.UrlReferrer.Host;

    // This is the host name of your application 
    string strUrlHost = Request.Url.Host;

    // I read the query string parameters
    string strQSPars = Request.Url.Query ?? string.Empty;

    // If the referer is not the application host (... someone manipulated the qs)...  
    // and    there is a query string parameter (be sure of this otherwise nobody can access the default page of your site
    // because this page has always a local referer...)
    if (strRefererHost != strUrlHost && strQSPars != string.Empty)
        Response.Redirect("~/WrongReferer.aspx"); // your error page

}
```

Comment: But its very easy to break since http headers as sent in plain text over network.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using this little open source library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Univar.aspx

It uses a unique key for each client computer and comes with many other goodies.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a good idea to add a parameter with a hash of all the other parameters. It prevents radically the querystring manipulation, but you have to think about the problem that means  use those URLs in other pages of your application, send those URLs to the public or use them in any printed way. You need to have a very good way to order and to have them at hand speccially if those pages are not dynamically created, or if you just need to add those URLs by hand.

I don't see any other problem about it. Some one may tell you that the hash can be calculated, but you can play with the order of the parameters obtaining different hashes and making very difficult to guess.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem with this is that javascript would have to do client-side SHA calculations just to link to pages, this of course depends on how much you use JS but it shouldn't be unresonable to think that a get argument might include pageNo=1, and to have a 'jump to page' input box, this would be made difficult if you add a hash. You could store in a session (server side) anything that you really don't want manipulated.