# How to encrypt/decrypt url in C#.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt query strings in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492878/how-to-encrypt-query-strings-in-asp-net)

I am creating one project in asp.net 4.0. I want to encrypt/ decript my url for the security reason/ How can i do this

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to do? What is 'my url'?

Comment: do you want encrypt url or query string?

Comment: i would like to encrypt whole url not only the query string.

Comment: Then how is the user supposed to use it? The browser can't automatically decrypt a URL...

Comment: are you wanting to encrypt part of the url such as.

http://mywebsite.com/4j3hr84hj943

Where "4j3hr84hj943" is an encrypted path that your web application will decode and handle appropriately?

Or are you talking about securing a connection with SSL?

Comment: Can I encrypt Folder Name.
Like My page is in www.xyz.com/Abc/a.aspx
I want to encrypt Abc 
Can I do that

Comment: @Govind, of course it's possible, if the OP is the proprietor of the server and controls all incoming data. It's not hard to write something that decrypts any URL that enters via an HttpModule, and then redirecting to where they need to go. Of course, the filter for the HttpModule needs to be *very* accepting.

Comment: However, depending on what you *actually* want to achieve, another approach might be better. What *do* you want to achieve? What is the purpose? Why do you want to encrypt the path?

Answer (score 1):

This is good article for make URL tamper free...
https://web.archive.org/web/20210125142425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/083105-1.aspx