# dotnetnuke : membership in mobile and webpages

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

We are building a mobile application which integrate through the DNN.

The mobile application uses ASP.net webservice which connect to the DNN Modules, in the mobile application there exist two options

the first option:

- the registration screen

which create new user in the DNN Module,  the problem is that in the ASP.net Web service the webmethod that is reponsible for creating the new user, it connect to the DNN database and insert new record in the tables (membership tables)

- aspnet_Membership

-aspnet_Users

-Users

the problem is that when insering new users in these table specially

([aspnet_Membership]) using ASP.net code and Linq.sql Framework

for these fields

,[Password]

,[PasswordFormat]

,[PasswordSalt]

we sypher the user password with Trible DES Algrithem

we creating class to generate salt and encrypt and decrypt passwords

```
public class NetFourMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public string GenerateSalt()
    {
        var buf = new byte[20];

        (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
    }

    public string EncodePassword(byte passFormat, string passtext, string passwordSalt)
    {
        if (passFormat.Equals(0)) // passwordFormat="Clear" (0)
            return passtext;
        else
        {
            byte[] bytePASS = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(passtext);
            byte[] byteSALT = Convert.FromBase64String(passwordSalt);
            byte[] byteRESULT = new byte[byteSALT.Length + bytePASS.Length + 1];

            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(byteSALT, 0, byteRESULT, 0, byteSALT.Length);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytePASS, 0, byteRESULT, byteSALT.Length, bytePASS.Length);

            if (passFormat.Equals(1)) // passwordFormat="Hashed" (1)
            {
                HashAlgorithm ha = HashAlgorithm.Create(Membership.HashAlgorithmType);

                return (Convert.ToBase64String(ha.ComputeHash(byteRESULT)));
            }
            else // passwordFormat="Encrypted" (2)
            {
                return (Convert.ToBase64String(this.EncryptPassword(byteRESULT)));
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetClearTextPassword(string encryptedPwd)
    {
        byte[] encodedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPwd);
        byte[] bytes = this.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword);

        if (bytes == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0x10, bytes.Length - 0x10).Substring(0, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0x10, bytes.Length - 0x10).Length - 1);
    }

    public new byte[] EncryptPassword(byte[] password)
    {
        return base.EncryptPassword(password);
    }
}
```

and adding in web.config file the sypher key

at app setting section we add

at the system.web secton we add

`<machineKey validationKey="42441B48BCA3F15B2353E426BC2C9111680E09E8" decryptionKey="00B3BAE82FEF44753E95AE088CCDB5E75C0F3BB1E58DEC2A" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1" />`

and the code for the register web servce is

```
  try
        {

            string Email = Request.QueryString["Email"];
            string UserName = Request.QueryString["UserName"];
            string MobileNo = Request.QueryString["MobileNo"];
            string FirstName = Request.QueryString["FirstName"];
            string LastName = Request.QueryString["LastName"];
            string password = Request.QueryString["Password"];
            string salt = "35wj1+r/Dr6RYjBbIRhWeQ==";

            NetFourMembershipProvider decriptor = new NetFourMembershipProvider();

            string encryptedpassword = decriptor.EncodePassword(2, password, salt);

            ORMDataContext myContext = new ORMDataContext();

            int userCount = (from user in myContext.Users
                             where user.Username == UserName
                             select user.UserID).Count();

            CustomUser myUser = new CustomUser();

            if (userCount == 0)
            {
                aspnet_User membership_user = new aspnet_User();

                membership_user.ApplicationId = Guid.Parse("4985C01A-3338-49C9-AC39-DC5934D5ED7A");
                membership_user.UserName = UserName;
                membership_user.LoweredUserName = UserName.ToLower();
                membership_user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
                membership_user.IsAnonymous = false;
                membership_user.MobileAlias = MobileNo;
                membership_user.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();

                myContext.aspnet_Users.InsertOnSubmit(membership_user);
                myContext.SubmitChanges();

                aspnet_Membership membership = new aspnet_Membership();

                Guid appID = Guid.Parse("4985C01A-3338-49C9-AC39-DC5934D5ED7A");

                membership.ApplicationId = appID;
                membership.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                membership.Email = Email;
                membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0;
                membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = DateTime.Now;
                membership.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0;
                membership.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = DateTime.Now;
                membership.IsApproved = true;
                membership.IsLockedOut = true;
                membership.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.Now;
                membership.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                membership.LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.Now;
                membership.LoweredEmail = Email.ToLower();
                membership.MobilePIN = "";
                membership.Password = encryptedpassword;
                membership.PasswordAnswer = "";
                membership.PasswordFormat = 2;
                membership.PasswordQuestion = "";
                membership.PasswordSalt = salt;
                membership.UserId = membership_user.UserId;

                myContext.aspnet_Memberships.InsertOnSubmit(membership);

                myContext.SubmitChanges();

                Borsa_Ws.User user = new User();

                user.Username = UserName;
                user.CreatedOnDate = DateTime.Now;
                user.DisplayName = UserName;
                user.Email = Email;
                user.FirstName = FirstName;
                user.LastName = LastName;
                user.UpdatePassword = false;
                user.LastModifiedByUserID = -1;
                user.IsSuperUser = false;

                myContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
                myContext.SubmitChanges();

                Borsa_Ws.UserRole user_role1 = new Borsa_Ws.UserRole();

                user_role1.UserID = user.UserID;
                user_role1.RoleID = 1;

                Borsa_Ws.UserRole user_role2 = new Borsa_Ws.UserRole();

                user_role2.UserID = user.UserID;
                user_role2.RoleID = 2;
                myContext.UserRoles.InsertOnSubmit(user_role1);
                myContext.UserRoles.InsertOnSubmit(user_role2);
                myContext.SubmitChanges();
                myUser.Roles = new int[] { 1, 2 };
                myUser.Logged = "1";
                myUser.UserID = user.UserID.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                myUser.Logged = "0";
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer searlizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            Response.Write(searlizer.Serialize(myUser));
            Response.End();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

wehen we come to the DNN web site and trying to login we the new inserted data

the DNN refuse the login

so could you  tell me what is rowng with my code

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has been very useful for me!  I found a mistake in it that would result in passwords not matching and potentially then not being able to login.  The line:

```
byte[] byteRESULT = new byte[byteSALT.Length + bytePASS.Length+1];
```

should be:

```
byte[] byteRESULT = new byte[byteSALT.Length + bytePASS.Length];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Badr,

Directly adding data to aspnet_membership and users table is not suggested, use DotNetNuke API to [create new user](http://truedeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/05/create-user-programmatically-in.html).

Also noticed the web service will require a [hash key validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061134/prevent-query-string-manipulation-by-adding-a-hash) to make sure intended audience is using your registration service.